# cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<QtNodes::DataFlowGraphicsScene>' to 'QtNodes::BasicGraphicsScene *'

Tags: c++, stl

```
mGraphicsView = std::make_shared<QtNodes::GraphicsView>(mGraphicsScene, parent);
```

The constructor takes a QtNodes::BasicGraphicsScene* as an argument, and I have an std::shared_ptr for that object. If I try to pass the shared pointer object directly as shown above, I get the following error:

```
cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<QtNodes::DataFlowGraphicsScene>' to 'QtNodes::BasicGraphicsScene *'
```

Now, If I use the .get() function, It does work, but since I am passing the raw pointer without calling the copy constructor, the reference count in my shared_ptr will not increase. Therefore, the object might get deleted while still in use.

How do I pass my object pointer while also updating the reference counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.

You have two options to keep the object alive while the consumer is processing it:

1. The caller takes care that the object stays around long enough.
2. The consumer accepts a `std::shared_ptr` instead of a raw pointer.

In a case where the first option is not simple to achieve *and* there is already a `std::shared_ptr`, the second option is clearly preferred.